# serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

Tags: python, arduino-uno

i'm making a web server that can contro an arduino with python
and i get this error:
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

```
from flask import Flask
from pyfirmata import Arduino
import time





main_page = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Button</h2>
<form action="button">
    <button type="submit">Press Button!</button>

<form>

</body>
</html>
"""

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/button')



def button():
    board = Arduino('COM3')
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    print("hello")
    return main_page

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return main_page


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: `COM3` is apparently not the right port number for your Arduino.  Check the Device Manager to see what it actually is.

Comment: i have looked in the device manager but the only arduino there is the com3

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue and by checking com3 in device manager i found it disabled, enabled it and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with few processes:

1. Open device manager.
2. Open ports(COM & LPT)
3. Unplug and plug your Arduino USB cable.
4. New port will get added. (eg. USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM6))
5. Go to Arduino IDE.
6. Under tools find port
7. Click and change to your cable port (My case COM6)